# AngularJS: ng-click and select text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

In my app i'm using some logic after my element was clicked.

For example:

html

```
<h3 ng-click="showAlert('text')">this is text! (try to click and select)</h3>
```

js

```
$scope.showAlert = function(text) {
  console.log('click!');
};
```

and when i click on element: all is ok. All done, as was expected.

But!

Why, when i try to select text, my event is fired too?

how to skip select event?

[image]

plunker: [click](http://plnkr.co/edit/ooMB7rtx26C08esY36Fl?p=preview)

Comment: There is no separate event for selection - so click will trigger anyway. You can make some checks on current selection, etc.etc. But I feel all this will hardly works good. Btw, clicking text is so unnatural behavior...

Comment: @PetrAveryanov for example toggling of editor (as `jira` do)

Comment: y, ok forgot about texteditables)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the time between a `mousedown` and a `mouseup` to determine if it's a click or the text is being selected.

Like so:
[Demo](https://jsbin.com/vuhojatabi/edit?html,js,console,output)

```
(function(){
  angular.module("app", []);

  angular.module("app")
  .directive("noclick", function(){
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      link: function(scope, element, attr){
        scope.time= Date.now();

        element.on("mousedown mouseup", function(e){
          if(e.type == "mousedown"){
            scope.time= Date.now();
          }

          if(e.type == "mouseup"){
            if(Date.now() - scope.time> 300){
              return false;
            }else{
              console.log("clicked");
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
})(window, angular);
```

Note: I'm using a directive for this case.

Comment: i would set 100 msec, anyways +1

Comment: and if I press mouse button slowly -> no click ( may be u want to compare coordinates also... Smells bad anyway)

Comment: @MaximShoustin, Yes, I was using 300 in canvas game, 100 is better for this case though. Thanks.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov, how slowly?

Comment: i can click, drink coffee and release it) Also there is double click that selects a word and will trigger click 2 times.

Comment: @Xlander please give idea, how to do not trigger checking on right button click. Thank you!

Comment: seems that this is working for me:

http://pastebin.com/nbtkhA6b

but maybe there are some other tricky solution?

Comment: @brabertaser1992, It's a good way to do it and I don't see any other ways to trigger only on left click.

Comment: This is really clean but a more robust version would be to check mouse movement instead of time. This way click works the way it does everywhere else.